# Microsoft Excel - Date Sequence

Tags: excel, date, time, spreadsheet, clock

I had a look for this question before I asked, but sorry if it's a repeat.
In a spreadsheet, I want to employ a date sequence.

eg. Stock Arrives      -    Friday 22nd February 2013
then, on the 22nd of Feb, that date CHANGES to the next 7 days. 
eg. Stock Arrives -         1st March 2013
and then repeats this indefinitely.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to see the sequence 2/22, 3/1, 3/8, 3/15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to always show the next Friday you can use this formula

`=TODAY()+8-WEEKDAY(TODAY()+2)`

That will show Friday 15th Feb 2013 right now.....but on 15th feb it will change to showing 22nd Feb

For other days just change the +2 at the end, e.g. +3 will give you next Thursday, +4 will give you next Wednesday, +5 will give you next Tuesday etc.

Comment: This is what I want, yes, but I'm not exactly sure how you've formatted it. Am I supposed to put anything in the brackets, and do I replace the TODAY and WEEKDAY values?

Comment: @DanielNitschke do not hesitate to try - the solution is working as it is))

Comment: As Peter says you can use the formula exactly as written you don't need to put anything in the brackets. All Excel functions come with brackets attached, for most of them you do have to enter something in the brackets but not for =TODAY() - that simply generates the current system date

Comment: So if i wanted it to change to for example, a different product, every monday? How would I edit this formula?

Also, the current format is american 2/13/13, any way to change it to like       Wednesday, 13th February?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how the day can be changed as required (to Monday, Tuesday etc.). To change how the date is displayed just format as required, right click on cell with date(s) and choose `Format Cells > Number > Date` and either choose any of the inbuilt formats from the list or you can choose `Custom` and type a format in the box - I think the one you want should be built in but if not use `dddd, d mmmm` you won't get the "th" part - that would need conditional formatting or a change to the formula

Answer (score 0):

This is some way you could do this though I am not sure if this is what you want.

`=B1+FLOOR((TODAY()-B1)/7,1)*7`

Basically, have a cell hold the start date of the stock inventory (first date in the past where you received this stock). You need to have also the number of days between restocking (here I hardcoded 7). Then you can just use the floor of the difference between today and that date divised by the restocking time. This will give you a step-function-style behaviour.